# two column accordion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using chakra ui and react .

I have problem that I want to use two column accordion . and when I am exapnding the one acordion another one is affected as well .

there is no hints from docs .

here is my code ->

```
<Accordion allowMultiple>
                    <Flex {...styles.flex} wrap="wrap" columnGap="8%">
                        {arr.map((item, index) => (
                            <AccordionItem flex="46%" borderTop="0" borderBottom="1px solid black">
                                <h2 style={{lineHeight: '25px', padding: '30px 30px 30px 0'}}>
                                    <AccordionButton>
                                        <Box as="span" flex="1" textAlign="left">
                                            Section {index + 1} title
                                        </Box>
                                        <AccordionIcon />
                                    </AccordionButton>
                                </h2>
                                <AccordionPanel pb={4}>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                                    enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                </AccordionPanel>
                            </AccordionItem>
                        ))}
                    </Flex>
                </Accordion>
```

if someone had same issue , how did you fix that? many thanks in advance.

Comment: flexbox can't do what you want. You are laying out your items in rows here, and the height of a row is determined by its largest element.

Comment: and can you suggest how can I achieve same without flexbox? Thansk a lot for answer

Comment: You'd have to lay the items out in columns instead of rows to begin with. Only, I doubt any mechanism to do that _automatically_ might not work too well here - because if element sizes change, it might also change were the browser makes the "break", deciding which items go into what column. Maybe using `columns` instead of flex, and putting the right combination of `break-before`/`break-inside`/`break-after` with the appropriate `avoid`/`always` values onto all the items could work ...